# Logstash service doesnt use config

Tags: logstash, logstash-configuration

Logstash service doesn't want to read my conf file in `/etc/logstash/conf.d/`.
Service is running all the time.

For example:

```
...
output {
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
    file { path => "/home/vagrant/LOGSTASH_TEST.txt" }
}
```

And nothing is added to the file.

But when I'm running `bin/logstash -f /etc/logstash/conf.d/myconfig.conf` — everything is fine.

`/etc/init.d/logstash` is looking good:

```
LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
...
program=/opt/logstash/bin/logstash
args="agent -f ${LS_CONF_DIR} -l ${LS_LOG_FILE} ${LS_OPTS}"
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: May be you need to also define `LS_CONF_FILE`? Try to echo `LS_CONF_FILE` and see what it points to. Actually I think you should give the full path to -f parameter like that: `args="agent -f ${LS_CONF_DIR}/${LS_CONF_FILE} -l ${LS_LOG_FILE} ${LS_OPTS}"`

Comment: Check that you don't have other files in that directory.  The one that works is specifying a single file where the one that doesn't is specifying the entire directory.

Comment: Ye. Thats definitely not the solution. Upgrading from 1.4 to latest 2.1 is the solution for me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try changing `/etc/init.d/logstash` to:

```
LS_CONF_DIR=/etc/logstash/conf.d
LS_CONF_FILE=myconfig.conf
...
program=/opt/logstash/bin/logstash
args="agent -f ${LS_CONF_DIR}/${LS_CONF_FILE} -l ${LS_LOG_FILE} ${LS_OPTS}"
```

Comment: I suppose the problem is that something wrong with file permissions.

Comment: then try choosing a log folder accessible by everyone - just for the test. By the way logs usually go in `/var/log` and not in `/home` directory (in most distros).

Comment: After some pause I decided to install latest version at the moment (2.1) and I was using 1.4. Everything is working okay now. Thanks for help.

Comment: If you consider that your solution might help someone else with the same problem, add it as an answer